# Windows batch script: Pipe text into a command line application

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm writing a batch script to automate some 3D printing processes. Right now, my code looks like this:

```
echo connect COM5 230400>3dprint.txt
echo load 3dprint01.gcode>>3dprint.txt
echo print>>3dprint.txt
type 3dprint.txt | C:\Printrun\pronsole.exe
```

So Pronsole is a command-line application that takes user-inputted commands (like connect, load and print above). Above, I've made the batch file create a text file and pass that into the application - except when it hits the EOF, this causes pronsole to crash.

**Is there an alternate way to pass (stdin style) text to this command line application that doesn't send an EOF?**

NB. The text commands don't all need to be sent at once either, but I imagine piping each line would cause a new instance of pronsole.exe to be opened each time?

Answer (score 0):

This may suffer the same issue.  Also try removing the terminal CR/LF in the txt file.

```
C:\Printrun\pronsole.exe <3dprint.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There simply isn't an `EOF` at the end of `3dprint.txt` AFAIAA.

I'd try appending a line with the `exit` command for `pronsole.exe`, whatever that is. `EXIT` maybe, or `QUIT`